# Purpose of z property with real value in QML ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml

In the below sample code, I set z property for the highlight item and depending on the value, it shows up to the user. The z property can also be configured with real value.

It means z value can have fractional values such as 0.1 or 1.2, like that.

Can anyone explain the purpose of z value should be fractional or real value in QML ListView?

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Sample List View")

    property var delHeight: 50

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        cacheBuffer: 100
        footer: Rectangle {
            width: (listView.orientation === ListView.Horizontal) ? 200 : parent.width
            height: delHeight
            color: "lightyellow"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.pointSize: 20
                text: "Footer"
            }
        }
        header: Rectangle {
            width: (listView.orientation === ListView.Horizontal) ? 200 : parent.width
            height: delHeight
            color: "lightblue"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.pointSize: 20
                text: "Header"
            }
            z: 2
        }
        headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
        highlight: Rectangle {
            color: "white"
            opacity: 0.5
            border.color: "blue"
            border.width: 5
            z: 1.2
            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log ("Created hightlight component with z factor: " + z)
            }
        }
//        highlightMoveDuration: 10000
//        highlightRangeMode: ListView.ApplyRange
        keyNavigationEnabled: true
        model: 20
        delegate: componentId
        layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
        orientation: ListView.Vertical
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem

        Component.onCompleted: {
            currentIndex = 5
        }
        focus: true
        onFocusChanged: {
            console.log ("Focus: " + focus)
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: componentId
        Rectangle {
            width: (listView.orientation === ListView.Horizontal) ? 200 : parent.width
            height: delHeight
            color: "lightgreen"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: (listView.currentIndex === index) ? 5 : 1
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.pointSize: 20
                text: "Element: " + index
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    listView.currentIndex = index
                }
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log ("Created component: " + index)
            }
            Component.onDestruction: {
                console.log ("Destroyed component: " + index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `z` property of an `item` gives the stacking order to that item.

Meaning, if you are constructing two Rectangles one after the other than recently constructed rectangle will be stacked on top the previously constructed one.

Ex code:

```
Item {
    Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        width: 100; height: 100
    }
    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        x: 50; y: 50; width: 100; height: 100
    }
}
```

Here `red` rectangle stacked below `blue` rectangle.

Now `QML` gives you chance to change the stacking order through `z` property of the item.

in the above example if I assign `z` property of the `red` rectangle to have a value of anything above 0, I would see it on top of `blue` rectangle. So `z` property has changed the stacking order for the sibling item.

The purpose of the `z` property stays the same in case of ListView highlight. When you want to see the highlight item then you have to give it a value which is greater than the items which will be constructed. You can check this by just setting `z` property for the `componentId`s rectangle to some higher value than highlights `z` value.

NOTE: it only works for sibling items.

More explanation can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop)
Read about the real type [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-real.html)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think the question here is why z is real value instead of integers?